# Assign key and variable without need to assign in Schema

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following mongodb / mongoose Schema

```
var forumReplySchema   = new Schema({
    userid : String,
    username: String,
    forumid: {type: String, default: '1'},
    message: {type: String, default: ''},
    time: Number,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('forum_replies', forumReplySchema);
```

with following query:

```
     forum_replies.findOne({forumid: forumid}).then(function (reply) {
    currentReply.username = user.username;
currentReply.rank = result.rank;

});
```

Currently `username` is assigned cause i have username property in the Schema.
`Rank` is not assigned cause its not in the Schema.

But is there a way for me to assign rank, without having it defined in the Schema?

Edit: aka, assign rank to the forum replies object without the need to save in Db.

Comment: is rank a new property that you wish to store in db?

Comment: No @SamipSuwal  i just want to store IT in the objects list. Without saging to db. Just want to store in same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot add properties to mongoose document. If you want to do so, you will need to convert it into plain object first. There are couple of ways you could go about it. Following is one of them.

```
reply.toObject();
```

Then you can add properties to it.

```
//you have currentReply in your code, I just want to show general idea here
reply.rank = result.rank;
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Update:

Thanks for accepting answer :). Also look into [lean()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) option, this returns you plain JS objects without you having to do the conversion manually. lean() also has performance benefit.

Comment: Without testing,it seems like that's what I'm after for,